# Dynamic table using string builder issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a dynamic table with stringbuilder. And i got a table with a root element. The requirement is while clicking this root element, the child tables should populate. So how to write the click event for this root table?
I have tried the following code. The onclick event is not firing.

```
StringBuilder Builder = new StringBuilder();

Builder.Append(@"<table border=1;").Append("id=Tableid;").Append("onclick=GetchildDiv()>").Append("<tr><td>").Append(Mainrow["Title"]).Append("</td></tr></table>");
```

Comment: Is it Webforms, Webpages or MVC ?

Comment: Please reformat the code snippet.

Comment: what is the output of `Builder.toString()` ? Is it what is expected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need spaces between attributes, **not** semi-colons (`;`). And you should quote the attribute values:

```
Builder.Append(@"<table border=""1"" ")
       .Append("id=\"Tableid\" ")
       .Append("\"onclick=GetchildDiv();\">")
       .Append("<tr><td>")
       .Append(Mainrow["Title"])
       .Append("</td></tr></table>");
```

Though you *could* use [`AppendFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat.aspx) instead, for readability:

```
Builder.Append(@"<table border=""1"" id=""Tableid"" onclick=""GetchildDiv();"">")
Builder.AppendFormat(@"<tr><td>{0}</td></tr></table>", Mainrow["Title"]);
```

Comment: `Builder.FormatAppend` is wrong too. Isn't it? I think he should use `Builder.AppendFormat`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is wrong. Try this:

```
Builder
    .Append(@"<table border=1 ") // remove semi-colon and add space
    .Append("id=Tableid ") // remove semi-colon and add space
    .Append("onclick=\"GetchildDiv();\">") // wrap the function-name by "
    .Append("<tr><td>")
    .Append(Mainrow["Title"])
    .Append("</td></tr></table>");
```

Comment: By default of HTML no, but xhtml and html5 YES! That means is better (OR in xhtml and html5, we can tell SHOULD) to wrap all `value`s by `"` in a html-tag `name-value` attributes

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using the StringBuilder, right.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder Builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
Builder.Append("<table border=\"1\" ").
    Append("id=\"Tableid\" ").
    Append("onclick=\"GetchildDiv()\">").
    Append("<tr><td>").
    Append(Mainrow["Title"]).
    Append("</td></tr></table>");
```

if you doing MVC i suggest to use the TagBuilder class.